# Convert YV12 (yuv420p) to JPEG / Bitamp

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap, yuv

In `onPreviewFrame` using `android.hardware.Camera`, if I use the default `NV21` format, I can use `YuvImage` to compress to jpeg format, which works great. If I try to change the format using `setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12)`, then it does not work anymore as `YuvImage` does not support `YV12` format. I've found only one solution somewhere to convert `Bitmap` to `YV12`, but I want to do the opposite and get a jpeg out of these bytes. Is there a library to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If YUV420 to JPEG is what you're looking for then,

```
@Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ByteArrayOutputStream out= new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        decodeYUV420(pixels, data, previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, previewSize.width, previewSize.height,Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG    , 25, out);
        .......
```

where, the decodeYUV420 method goes as follows:

```
public void decodeYUV420(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
}
```

I've created a similar project to this on github check [here](https://github.com/shahsurajk/ARS2)

and the code implementation: [here](https://github.com/shahsurajk/ARS2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/RemoteSurveillance/ARS2/SpyConnection.java)

and yes it works!

Comment: you confirm this is for `yuv420p` and not `yuv420sp` right?

Comment: wait. let me check.

Comment: looks more like of yuv420sp. since there's one yuv array. let me check if theres a way to sample yuv420p to yuv20sp

Comment: can you try it once. i cannot replicate with yuv420p. but should work.

Comment: im glad it did!